# Computing to volume of ball intersection with cone and another ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, volume, multiple-integral

I am trying to calculate the integral $\ \int\int\int_V z dV $ where $\ V $ is the volume inside the ball $\ x^2 + y^2 + (z-2)^2 = 4 $ and also inside the cone $\ z^2 = x^2 + y^2 $ and outside the ball $\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 $ .

So my attempt it to set the limits of $\ z $ integral from the lower ball to the higher ball. so $\ z $ should start at $\ \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} $ and ends at $\ \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} + 2 $ and the project of the intersection of cone with the ball is a circle with radius of $\ \sqrt{2} $ and so $ x $ will go from $\ - \sqrt{2-y^2} $ to $ \sqrt{2-y^2} $ and $\ y $ from $\ -\sqrt{2} $ to $ \sqrt{2} $

I don't know how to convert though. What should be $\ \theta, \phi , r $ ? trying to use the formula the outcome doesn't seem reasonable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = rsin\theta cos\phi$

$y = rsin\theta sin\phi$

$z = rcos\theta$

$x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$

$dxdydz = r^2sin\theta \ dr \ d\theta \ d\phi$

Case1:

$x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2 = 4$

$$r = 2$$

Case2:

$x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2 - 4z +4 = 4$

$r^2 - 4rcos\theta = 0$

$$r = 4cos\theta$$

(refer the graph for $r\not=0$)

$\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/4$

and

$\phi$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$

[image]

---

Solution:

$ I = \int^{2\pi}_{\phi = 0} \ \int^{\pi/4}_{\theta = 0}\ \int^{4\cos\theta}_{r=2} r^3\cos\theta \ \sin\theta dr \ d\theta \ d\phi$

$I = [\int^{2\pi}_{\phi = 0}d\phi]\ \int^{\pi/4}_{\theta = 0}\bigg[\frac{r^4}{4}\bigg]^{4cos\theta}_2 sin\theta cos\theta d\theta$

$I = [2\pi].\frac{1}{4}\bigg[\int^{\pi/4}_{\theta = 0}\big[4^4cos^4\theta.cos\theta.sin\theta d\theta] + \int^{\pi/4}_{\theta = 0}\big[(-2^4)sin\theta.cos\theta.d\theta\big]\bigg]$

$I = \frac{\pi}{2}\bigg[\int^{\pi/4}_{\theta = 0}\big[4^4cos^5\theta d(- cos\theta)] + \int^{\pi/4}_{\theta = 0}\big[(-2^3)sin2\theta d\theta\big]\bigg]$

$I = \frac{\pi}{2}\bigg[\big[\frac{- 4^4cos^6\theta}{6}]^{\pi/4}_0 + 2^3\big[\frac{\cos 2\theta}{2}\big]^{\pi/4}_0\bigg]$

$I = \frac{\pi}{2}\bigg[\frac{-128}{3}(\frac{1}{8} -1) + 4(0 -1)\bigg]$

$I = \frac{\pi}{2}\big[\frac{112}{3} - 4 \big]$

$I = \frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{100}{3})$

Thus, $$I = \frac{50\pi}{3} $$

---

Proof of the value:

$x = rsin\theta cos\phi$

$y = rsin\theta sin\phi$

$z = rcos\theta$

Computing partial derivatives,

$x_r = sin\theta cos\phi \ , x_{\theta} = rcos\theta cos\phi \ , x_{\phi} = -rsin\theta sin \phi$

$y_r = sin\theta sin\phi \ , y_{\theta} = rcos\theta sin\phi \ , y_{\phi} = rsin\theta cos \phi$

$z_r = cos\theta  \ , z_{\theta} = -rsin\theta  , z_{\phi} = 0$

$J = \
\begin{vmatrix}
sin\theta cos\phi  & rcos\theta cos\phi  & -rsin\theta sin \phi \\
sin\theta sin\phi &  rcos\theta sin\phi  &  rsin\theta cos \phi \\
cos\theta & -rsin\theta & 0
\end{vmatrix} $

Expanding along third row,

$J = cos\theta[r^2cos\theta sin\theta cos^2\phi \ + r^2cos\theta sin\theta sin^2\phi] + rsin\theta[rsin^2\theta cos^2\phi + rsin^2\theta sin^2\phi]$

$J = r^2sin\theta[cos^2\theta(cos^2\phi+sin^2\phi)] + r^2sin\theta[sin^2\theta(cos^2\phi+sin^2\phi)]$

$J = r^2sin\theta[cos^2\theta+sin^2\theta] = r^2sin\theta$

$$dxdydz = |J|dr d\theta d\phi = r^2sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! why does $\ dxdydz = r^2sin\theta \ dr \ d\theta \ d\phi $ as the original integral was just $\ \int \int \int z $ so I thought it should be $\ r^2 \cos \theta \ dr \ d \theta \ d \phi $ ?

Comment: We have $dv = dxdydz = r^2sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$. As you need $zdv$ just use $z = rcos\theta$ along with dv. And the value is calculated through Jacobians, I'll try to attach it with my answer.

Comment: I've attached the derivation of the formula. You may refer it.

Comment: So you the final integral should be $\ \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_2^{4cos\theta} r \cos \theta r^2 \sin \theta \ dr \ d\theta \ d \phi $ ?

Comment: Sorry , r varies from 2 to $4cos\theta$

Comment: Yes I hope so!!!

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, the final solution I get is $\ 0 $ while the actual answer is $\ 50\pi / 3 $ .  Thought maybe you could give me direction again as to where I am wrong??

Comment: I've added the solution, you may refer it :)

Comment: Thanks buddy !!!